# Pass variable to a Widget outside Stateful class

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the best way to pass variable (photoUrl) to a Widget?
Adding widget inside state class it says:  Only static members can be accessed in initializers.

Changing method to static neither solves my issue.

```
class _ABState extends State<AB> {
  int _selectedPage = 0;
  String photoUrl; /* Value set in initState()*/

  /* To switch between pages */
  final _pageOptions = [
    Text('Page 1'),
    accountPage(), /* Page 2 */
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _pageOptions[_selectedPage],
    );
  }
}

/* Widget outside class requires photoUrl */
Widget accountPage() {
  return Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: NetworkImage(photoUrl),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `accountPage()` at the initializer, but `photoUrl` is set only on `initState()`, so even if `accountPage()` had access to `photoUrl`, it would get the wrong value.

I suggest the following:

```dart
class _ABState extends State<AB> {
  int _selectedPage = 0;
  String photoUrl;
  List<Widget>_pageOptions;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    photoUrl = "<PLACE_YOUR_VALUE>";
    _pageOptions = [
      Text('Page 1'),
      accountPage(photoUrl),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _pageOptions[_selectedPage],
    );
  }
}

Widget accountPage(String photoUrl) {
  return Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: NetworkImage(photoUrl),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```